# React.js - Search with pagination interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building my first application with React.js.
The application uses external movie API (https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) to search and list movies.
The request takes parameters "query" and optionally "page". The response already contains total number of results and total number of existing pages.
The sample response looks something like this:

```
 {
 "page": 1,
 "results": [
  {
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/8uO0gUM8aNqYLs1OsTBQiXu0fEv.jpg",
  "genre_ids": [18],
  "id": 550,
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Fight Club",
  "overview": "A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.",
  "release_date": "1999-10-14",
  "poster_path": "/811DjJTon9gD6hZ8nCjSitaIXFQ.jpg",
  "popularity": 4.39844,
  "title": "Fight Club",
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 7.8,
  "vote_count": 3527
},
{
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/qrZssI8koUdRxkYnrOKMRY3m5Fq.jpg",
  "genre_ids": [
    27
  ],
  "id": 289732,
  "original_language": "zh",
  "original_title": "Zombie Fight Club",
  "overview": "It's the end of the century at a corner of the city in a building riddled with crime - Everyone in the building has turned into zombies. After Jenny's boyfriend is killed in a zombie attack, she faces the challenge of surviving in the face of adversity. In order to stay alive, she struggles with Andy to flee danger.",
  "release_date": "2014-10-23",
  "poster_path": "/7k9db7pJyTaVbz3G4eshGltivR1.jpg",
  "popularity": 1.621746,
  "title": "Zombie Fight Club",
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 3.5,
  "vote_count": 2
}
],
  "total_pages": 1,
  "total_results": 2
}
```

The structure, that I have picked is the following:

```
MovieSearchPage
- SearchForm
- SearchResults
--MovieBox
--Pagination
---Page
```

Here's my solution, which almost works fine:

```
        var SearchResults = React.createClass({
            handlePageChange: function(pageNum) {
                this.props.onPageChange(pageNum);
            },
            render: function() {
                var movies = [];

                this.props.data.results.forEach(function(movie) {
                    movies.push(<MovieBox movie={movie} key={movie.id}/>);
                });

                return (
                   <div>
                   <h3>Search results ({this.props.data.total_results} found)</h3>
                   <Pagination onPageClick={this.handlePageChange} currentPage={this.props.data.page} totalPages={this.props.data.total_pages} totalResults={this.props.data.total_results}/>
                   <div>{movies}</div>
                   </div>
                );
            }
        });

        var SearchBar = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
                return {query: ''};
            },
            handleQueryChange: function(e) {
                this.setState({query: e.target.value});
            },
            handleSubmit: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var query = this.state.query.trim();
                if (!query || query.length < 3) {
                    return;
                }
                this.props.onSearch(query);
            },
            render: function() {
                return (
                   <form className="searchForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="query" 
                        placeholder="Search for a movie..."
                        value={this.state.query}
                        onChange={this.handleQueryChange}
                    />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search Movie"/>
                   </form>
                );
            }
        });

        var MovieBox = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                var m = this.props.movie;
                return (
                   <div className="movieBox">
                        <div>{m.original_title} ({m.release_date})</div>
                   </div>
                );
            }
        });

        var Pagination = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                var pages = [];
                var total = this.props.totalPages;
                for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
                    pages.push(<Page key={i} onPageClick={this.props.onPageClick} pageNum={i} active={(this.props.currentPage == i) || false}/>);
                }
                return (
                    <div className="pagination">{pages}</div>
                );
            }
        });

        var Page = React.createClass({
            handleClick: function(e) {
                var pageNum = e.target.innerHTML;
                this.props.onPageClick(pageNum);
            },
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} className={this.props.active ? 'active' : ''}>{this.props.pageNum}</a>
                )
            }
        });

        var MovieSearchPage = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
                return {query: '', pageNum: 1, data: {results: [], total_pages: 0, total_results: 0}};
            },
            initSearch: function(query) {
                this.setState({query: query});
                this.doSearch(query, this.state.pageNum);
            },
            nextPage: function(pageNum) {
                this.setState({pageNum: pageNum});
                this.doSearch(this.state.query, pageNum);
            },
            doSearch: function(query, pageNum) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.props.url,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {query: query, api_key: this.props.apiKey, page: pageNum},
                    success: function(data) {
                        this.setState({data: data});
                    }.bind(this),
                    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            },
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <SearchBar onSearch={this.initSearch}/>
                        <SearchResults onPageChange={this.nextPage} data={this.state.data}/>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(
            <MovieSearchPage url="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie" apiKey=""/>,
            document.getElementById('container')
        );
```

The problem, that I am having here, is that initial search is performed within SearchForm, using "query" state, however, I want to perform search requests to API from clicking on pagination (same query string, but different page number) without reloading the page.

I managed to achieve this by passing relevant parent method from MovieSearchPage all the way down to Page component.

This works fine, but I firmly believe, that this is not the most elegant solution to do this - the same method is passed multiple times plus I had to duplicate "query" state in both MovieSearchBox and SearchForm.

Please forgive me being a noob, but this is really the first time I am using a complex front-end framework. What is the proper way to do it in order to achieve this?

Despite situation being very generic, I was not able to find anything on the web.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you need to call doSearch using the same query and page number from the pagination. Can you give each number an onClick="doSearch(QUERY, THIS PAGE NUMBER)"? I'm not familiar with React enough to give any code. I have done this exact thing outside of React, the logic should be the same.

Comment: The problem with React, as I think, is that you cannot simply call other component's method. In order to do this, you need to pass the callback method as an argument (or property as it is called in React.js) to a child component. Within my application I had to pass it all the way down from parent component (which is basically the page itself) to every single page link.